# How to get the value of Promise value of asynchronous method?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, es6-promise

I define a javascript that looks like thise:

```
async function searchPerson(item){
    const url = window.location;
    const response = await fetch(url.origin+"/api/persons/search/1/"+item);
    const person = await response.json();
    //console.log(person);
    return person;
}
```

and so in my `eventListener`, i am calling that method just like this:

```
if(document.getElementById('search-person')){
    document.getElementById('search-person').addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
         item = document.getElementById('input_search_person_ref_number').value;
         if(item){
             const person= async ()=>{
                 searchPerson(item);
             }
             //const person = await searchPerson(item);
             console.log(person);
         } 
    }
}
```

Upon running i am getting an out put like this:

```
async ()=>{
    searchPerson(item);
}
```

if i use `const person = await searchPerson(item);` i have to make `addEventListener` async too. Is there other way to get it (return value promise) without making `addEventListener` asynchronous?

Comment: You cannot expect to get a *future* result *now*. So you must embrace the `async` pattern *all the way*.  So `searchPerson(item).then(console.log)`

Comment: When calling an async function, you must either `await` it, or call `.then` on the resulting Promise. No good other way around it

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing it to me. By the way, is promise specify only for ES6 onwards? How can i detect if my javascript code is old one?